# Solving recurrence relation of two series with generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

I'd appreciate your advice on how to solve recurrence relations of the following kind using generating functions: 
general solution of:

\begin{cases}a_{n+1} &= 5a_n - 3b_n \\ b_{n+1} &= 4a_n - 2b_n\end{cases}

for $n>0$ and particular solution for $a_0 = 2, b_0 = 1$.

I know how to solve recursions where only one series, f.e. $(a_n)_n$ is involved, but not how to do this for $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ at once.

Comment: Note:  $a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}=(5a_n-3b_n)-(4a_n-2b_n)=a_n-b_n$ for this recurrence

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, I don't see how this does help?

Comment: It tells you that $a_{n+1}=5a_n-3b_n=5a_n-3(a_n-(a_0-b_0))=2a_n+3(a_0-b_0)$

Comment: Ah great, this is what I was looking for, thanks! :)

Comment: No, sorry, why can you substitute $b_n$ with $a_n-(a_0-b_0)$? I don't see that...?

Comment: by induction, $a_n-b_n=a_0-b_0$; therefore, $b_n=a_n-(a_0-b_0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akin to the matrix approach, simply eliminate one of the variables from the equation. For example,

$$3b_{n+1}=2a_{n+1}+2a_n$$

which can then be substituted into the definition of $a_{n+1}$ to get

$$a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}$$

which is now linear in one recurrence. Similarly, we have

$$4a_{n+1}=5b_{n+1}-2b_n$$

and hence,

$$b_{n+1}=3b_n-2b_{n-1}$$

Comment: Thanks you! What does this have to do with the matrix approach? 

I solved the relation in only $a_n$ after expressing $a_n$ like you did with $b_n$ and came to the solution $a_n = 5 \cdot 2^n - 3$, $b_n = 5 \cdot 2^n - 4$. Is this correct?

Comment: The matrix approach works somewhat similar, at least imo. And yes that should be fine.

Comment: Okay, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{n+1}\\ b_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}5 & -3\\ 4 & -2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{n}\\ b_{n}\end{pmatrix}$$

Diagonalize the square matrix to obtain
$$A_{n+1}=P^{-1}DPA_n$$
And then
$$A_n=P^{-1}D^nPA_0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate that. 
But I'm not familiar with the diagonalization, so I prefer another approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

For this *specific* one, you have that $a_n=b_n+1$ for all $n$:

Proof by induction:

Base: $a_0=b_0+1$

Step. Assume $a_n=b_n+1$

Then $a_{n+1} = 5a_n-3b_n=5(b_n+1)-3b_n=2b_n+5$

and $b_{n+1}=4a_n-2b_n=4(b_n+1)-2b_n=2b_n+4$

And so indeed $a_{n+1}=b_{n+1}+1$

OK, so then you have:

$a_{n+1}=5a_n-3b_n=5a_n-3(a_n-1)=2a_n+3$

and (as we already saw):

$b_{n+1}=2b_n+4$

And, you said that you can solve those yourself.

Comment: +1; I was just going to answer that; essentially $a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}=a_n-b_n$ for this recurrence

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How did you see this relation between $a_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: @Studentu You're welcome! I calculated $a_1$, $b_1$, $a_2$, and $b_2$, and at that point suspected the pattern.

Comment: Oh I see, thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

For this recurrence, $a_{n+1}−b_{n+1}=(5a_n−3b_n)−(4a_n−2b_n)=a_n−b_n$ for all $n,$ so $a_n-b_n=a_0-b_0$.

Therefore, $a_{n+1}=5a_n−3\color{blue}{b_n}=5a_n−3\color{blue}{(a_n−(a_0−b_0))}=2a_n+3(a_0−b_0). $

Now only one series $(a_n)$ is involved, so you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Oh thank you! I didn't realize that we get this by induction. :)